# Drag and Drop custom titled border box in Flex 4 problems

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, drag-and-drop, flash-builder

hope that someone flex experienced will be able to give the advice on that:

So I have the little flex 4 application which has custom titled border containers, I want to be able to drag and drop them between the containers but... d&d is simple when you deal with flex component, but this custom titled container is made of couple of parts such as: label, border container so... when I try to drag and drop that titled container then I can't grab the entire titled container but just one of its parts (label or border box) and when I do drop then flex throws errors that the element is not in the same group.

I know that it might not be the simplest explanation of the problem but maybe someone has meet with this already or have some experience with this, any help appreciated.

Hi, I've edited my question to give a better understanding of the problem, so I have the layout of the custom titled containers like this:

```
----Group A --------------------------------
|                                           |
|   --- Sub Group A --------------------    |
|   |                                   |   |
|   |   --- Item A1 --   --Item A2---   |   |
|   |   |         |     |            |  |   |
|   |   |         |     |            |  |   |
|   |   |-------------   ------------   |   |
|   |                                   |   |
|   |-----------------------------------    |
|                                           |
|-------------------------------------------

----Group B --------------------------------
|                                           |
|   --- Sub Group B --------------------    |
|   |                                   |   |
|   |   --- Item B1 --   --Item B2---   |   |
|   |   |         |      |           |  |   |
|   |   |         |      |           |  |   |
|   |   |-------------   ------------   |   |
|   |                                   |   |
|   |-----------------------------------    |
|                                           |
|-------------------------------------------
```

I I want to be able to swap the Group A with the Group B, also the children of the Group A and B (Sub Group A & B) have to be swap-able with each other, and finally the children of the Sub Groups A & B also have to be swap-able. Now I have managed to get the children of the Sub Groups swap-able, and also the Sub Groups can be swapped with each other but... 
Occasionally when I swap Sub Group A with B the Sub Grop A lands inside the Sub Group B. It is a working progress and I am posting the run-able code with my set up although the TitledContainer is not included and if you need this component let me know :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:titledContainer="titledContainer.*"
               >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.DragSource;
            import mx.core.IUIComponent;
            import mx.core.IVisualElement;
            import mx.events.DragEvent;
            import mx.managers.DragManager;

            import spark.components.SkinnableContainer;         


            //-------------------------------------------------------------------
            // ITEM BOXES DRAG FUNCTIONS
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------

            private function handleStartDrag( evt:MouseEvent ):void
            {
                // grab the item renderer and relevant data
                var dragItem:IUIComponent = evt.target as IUIComponent;
                var dragSource:DragSource = new DragSource();
                dragSource.addData( dragItem, "item" );
                DragManager.doDrag( dragItem, dragSource, evt );

            }

            protected function handleDragEnter( evt:DragEvent ):void
            {
                if( evt.dragSource.hasFormat( "item" ) )
                    DragManager.acceptDragDrop( evt.target as IUIComponent );

            }

            protected function handleDragDrop( evt:DragEvent ):void
            {
                var dragItem:Object = evt.dragSource.dataForFormat( "item" );
                var dragItemOwner:SkinnableContainer = ( dragItem.owner as
                    SkinnableContainer );
                dragItemOwner.removeElement( dragItem as IVisualElement );
                var targetOwner:SkinnableContainer = ( evt.target as
                    SkinnableContainer );
                targetOwner.addElement( dragItem as IVisualElement );
            }

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------
            // SUB GROUPS CONTAINERS DRAG FUNCTIONS
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------


            private function handleStartDragSub( evt:MouseEvent ):void
            {
                // grab the item renderer and relevant data
                var dragItem:IUIComponent = evt.target as IUIComponent;
                var dragSource:DragSource = new DragSource();
                dragSource.addData( dragItem, "item" );
                DragManager.doDrag( dragItem, dragSource, evt );

            }

            protected function handleDragEnterSub( evt:DragEvent ):void
            {
                if( evt.dragSource.hasFormat( "item" ) )
                    DragManager.acceptDragDrop( evt.target as IUIComponent );

            }

            protected function handleDragDropSub( evt:DragEvent ):void
            {
                var dragItem:Object = evt.dragSource.dataForFormat( "item" );
                var dragItemOwner:SkinnableContainer = ( dragItem.owner as
                    SkinnableContainer );
                dragItemOwner.removeElement( dragItem as IVisualElement );
                var targetOwner:SkinnableContainer = ( evt.target as
                    SkinnableContainer );
                targetOwner.addElement( dragItem as IVisualElement );
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- MAIN CONTAINER ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~-->
    <s:SkinnableContainer x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" >
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout />
        </s:layout>


        <!-- FIRST ROW ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~-->

        <s:SkinnableContainer width="100%" >
            <s:layout>
                <s:HorizontalLayout />
            </s:layout>

            <!-- First Group --> 
            <titledContainer:TitledContainer  label="Group A" width="50%" dragEnter="handleDragEnterSub(event)" dragDrop="handleDragDropSub(event)">
                <titledContainer:layout>
                    <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" gap="10"/>
                </titledContainer:layout>

                <s:Group width="100%"  mouseDown="handleStartDragSub(event);"  >
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:HorizontalLayout />
                    </s:layout>

                    <titledContainer:TitledContainer  label="Sub Group A" width="500" dragEnter="handleDragEnter(event)" dragDrop="handleDragDrop(event)">
                        <titledContainer:layout>
                            <s:HorizontalLayout paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" gap="10"/>
                        </titledContainer:layout>

                        <s:Group mouseDown="handleStartDrag(event);">

                            <titledContainer:TitledContainer  label="Item A 1"  >
                                <titledContainer:layout>
                                    <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" gap="10"/>
                                </titledContainer:layout>
                            </titledContainer:TitledContainer>

                        </s:Group> <!-- Item 1 end-->

                        <s:Group mouseDown="handleStartDrag(event);">

                            <titledContainer:TitledContainer  label="Item A 2"  >
                                <titledContainer:layout>
                                    <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" gap="10"/>
                                </titledContainer:layout>
                            </titledContainer:TitledContainer>

                        </s:Group> <!-- Item 2 end-->

                    </titledContainer:TitledContainer><!-- Front cover 2 end-->

                </s:Group>

                <s:Group width="100%"  mouseDown="handleStartDragSub(event);"  >
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:HorizontalLayout />
                    </s:layout>

                    <titledContainer:TitledContainer  label="Sub Group B" width="500" dragEnter="handleDragEnter(event)" dragDrop="handleDragDrop(event)">
                        <titledContainer:layout>
                            <s:HorizontalLayout paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" gap="10"/>
                        </titledContainer:layout>

                        <s:Group mouseDown="handleStartDrag(event);">

                            <titledContainer:TitledContainer  label="Item B3"  >
                                <titledContainer:layout>
                                    <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" gap="10"/>
                                </titledContainer:layout>
                            </titledContainer:TitledContainer>

                        </s:Group> <!-- Item 3 end-->

                        <s:Group mouseDown="handleStartDrag(event);">

                            <titledContainer:TitledContainer  label="Item B4"  >
                                <titledContainer:layout>
                                    <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" gap="10"/>
                                </titledContainer:layout>
                            </titledContainer:TitledContainer>

                        </s:Group> <!-- Item 4 end-->

                    </titledContainer:TitledContainer><!-- Front cover 3 end-->



                </s:Group> 

            </titledContainer:TitledContainer><!-- Front cover 1 end-->

        </s:SkinnableContainer> <!-- first row end-->


    </s:SkinnableContainer>

</s:Application>
```

Please note that I am a Flex and AS3 beginner so please be gentle on me,

The problem is to:

1. Be able to swap Groups, Sub Groups and Items with each other (maintaining the hierarchy) and disallow wrong placement ie: Sub Group A inside the Sub Group B etc.
2. When clicking the custom titled container the user should be able to drag the whole component rather that the title, or the border container or anything else what is inside the titled container.

Please be gentle on the beginner, I am not asking you to write the code for me, but rather the guidance how to do it properly but code samples are welcomed, thank you all.

Comment: You want to be able to drag and drop **WHAT** between the containers?  What errors does Flex throw?  Can you share some code?  Perhaps a runnable sample.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question so it is now more easy to understand, could you please have a look and possibly help me a bit, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Correct display object problem**

Pass the parent custom container to startDrag instead of its elements. To do that, you have to detect dragging as usual by listening to

```
MOUSE_DOWN, MOUSE_MOVE,
```

events.

I guess you did that already but, following the examples possibly you wrote

```
e.target.startDrag(false, new Rectangle(bla, bla));
```

Instead of writing

```
myCustomContainer.startDrag(false, new Rectangle(bla,bla));
```

For doing that there are two prerequisites:

1) Find the correct container that drag is occuring on if mouse is dancing on a subcontrol.
This can be relatively easy, if your controls are direct displayObject descendants, moving up on the display list parent tree, just checking for the container class will be sufficient. A very basic code example for detecting parent would be like:

```
public function detectMyContainer(t: DisplayObject){

while((t)&&(t !== root)){
    if(t is YourCustomContainer){
         return(t);
    }    
    t = DisplayObject(t).parent;
}
return(null);
}
```

2) You should not block the mouse down and mouse move event propagation in the subcontrols of the container, since this will render container deaf...

Now this will partially solve your problem, meaning instead of subcontrols up to now you are managing to find the correct parent and moving it.

**Correct group problem**

When you start dragging a displayObject, you should drop it on to the same parent.

If not, as you already have seen, as3 will yell at you...

If you want to move display objects across different parents, you should override this behaviour, you have follow the steps I will pseudo code below:

First of all you should decide on your ultimate parent DisplayObjectContainer which contains different parents that you will move childs across, generally this is the **stage** but we will call it **arena**.

Lets call the object being dragged **drag**.(yes I lack creativity at this hour) :).

1) Detect the **drag** correctly.

```
 look detectMyContainer.
```

2) Map the **drag** coordinates to **stage**.

```
 use localToGlobal.
```

3) If **arena** is **not stage** map the coordinates to **arena**.

```
 use globalToLocal
```

4) Remove **drag** from its parent and add to **arena**.

```
 use arena.addChild(drag)
```

5) Set drag.x and drag.y to the arena mapped coordinates. Now you have drag at the same place with a deeper parent...

6) start listening MOUSE_UP on **drag**

7) start dragging

```
 use drag.startDrag(...)
```

8) When mouse goes up, look at **drag**'s drop target... Now there

```
 first stopDrag()
```

9) Detect the dropTarget appropriately, it may not be what you guessed so look at its class, and parents etc to determine if there is a valid one and which.

10) if dropTarget does not exist, add **drag** back to original parent and set its original coordinates...(When you get used to things, you will tween animate this I bet).

11) Now map the **arena** coords of **drag** to **dropTarget**

```
 if arena is not stage make a localToGlobal for drag in arena

 make a globalToLocal for drag global to dropTarget local
```

12) Remove **drag** from **arena** and add it to its new parent **dropTarget**.

```
 use dropTarget.addChild(drag)
```

13) Set drag.x and drag.y to the dropTarget mapped coordinates.

Thats all, It is shorter when you code this, do not be afraid...

I wish you luck.

Comment: Hi Ihsan, thank you for you answer, I believe that it's provide the solution to this problem, I will follow you guidance and report back, thank you